# android app restart on changing layout on orientation change

Tags: android

I developed a music player app.I use the following code to change layout on  orientation change but app restarts and only layout changes app misbehaves and don't run continuously.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main_p)
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
       setContentView(R.layout.main_L)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go back to the activity life cycle, on rotation, the activity is destroyed and then recreated after the device is rotated. The MediaPlayer is released which stops the playback. This results in the discontinuity of the MediaPlayer. If you host MediaPlayer in the fragment, you can you use a feature to keep the MediaPlayer instance alive across a configuration change.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
   setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

Furthermore, you don't need to use onConfigurationChanged to change the layout on rotation. You can put the other layout with the exact same name on layout-land folder. That way the system will automatically switch to use the layout on layout-land folder if the orientation is landscape mode and layout in portrait mode.

Please prefer to developer.android.com for additional information:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html